# Object Inspector Button not enabled in python console of qgis

Tags: qgis, python-2.7

I am using QGIS2.6 version. I loaded an existing py file in a editor. Though I added a codes in the editor, the object inspector button was not enabled. Please help me in figuring out what would be the problem.

Comment: Are you trying to edit a read-only file?

Comment: Nope.It is not a read-only file. Even I made changes by adding a new function and saved. Still that was not enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can enable this button under the settings button within the Python console / editor.

Comment: Great! Problem solved.